# How to make a method that is ran when webservice method ends?

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a webservice and initiate a lot of methods in the constructor. I need a lot of these "ended" (such as database connections terminated etc), is there an easy and dandy way of doing this that is a bit like constructor (de-contructor), ie. a method ran at the end of the webservice method call? Repeating everything at the end of each method feels like there must be a smarter way.

My language of choice is c#

Comment: "ended"? Sorry, I can only understand if I see some code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this approach?

```
    private void WebMethodAction()
    {
        Execute(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        });
    }

    private int WebMethodFunc(int a, int b)
    {
        return Execute(() =>
        {
            return (double)a / (double)b;
        });
    }        

    public void Execute(Action action)
    {
        // call Execute<T> and discard result
        Execute(() => { action.Invoke(); return true; });
    }

    public T Execute<T>(Func<T> func)
    {
        T result = func.Invoke();

        // cleanup
        Console.WriteLine("Cleanup");

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Interesting approach... What about non-void methods ?

Comment: I updated my solution to show how to use this with Methods with return values.

Comment: I use this approach to log method execution times `log timestamp + func.method, execute, log timestamp + func.method, return result`

Comment: This isn't quite what I had in mind, but fits the purpose well. Thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [try finally](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz.aspx) and place all the tidying up in the finally section.

Place this inside the web service method:

```
[WebMethod]
public void DoSomething(string value)
{
    try
    {
       //Do Something
    }
    finally
    {
       //Tidy up after methods in the try have ended
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I need to put the same codeblock in to each "finally", which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.